# Help with JavaScript self-extending bit adder

Tags: javascript, binary

Hey guys, today i was inspired by a 16 bit ALU made in Mincraft to try and make my own self-extending adder.
I literally started JavaScript today, and have been playing around with logic gates over the past couple days. So I am very new to this.

Here is my code so far.

```
<html> 
<body> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        function add(ai, bi) {
        var newadd = [ai.length+1];
            for(i = 0 ; i < ai.length ; i ++) {
                if(i>0) {
                    newadd[i]=fullAdd(ai[i],bi[i],fullAdd(ai[i-1],bi[i-1],0).charAt(1)).charAt(0);;

                }
                else {
                    newadd[i]=fullAdd(ai[i],bi[i],0).charAt(0);

                }
            }
            return newadd;
        }

        function fullAdd(ai, bi, ci) {
            var ao = ((ai^bi)^ci);
            var co = (((ai^bi)&ci)|(ai&bi));
            return ao+""+co;
        }

        var a = [1,0];
        var b = [0,1];
        document.write("a + b = " + add(a,b));

    </script> 
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong?
I'm sure it is something silly or stupid, or that my self-devised system just won't work.
Anyways thanks for your help in advance!
-Devan

Note: the full adder does work and return the characters it should. The problem is the add function.

EDIT: fixed the 2 obvious mistakes

EDIT2: I have come close to the answer by changing the add function a bit.

EDIT3: Solved, here is the code that works

```
<html> 
<body> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        function add(ai, bi) {
        var newadd = [ai.length+1];
            for(i = 0 ; i < ai.length+1 ; i ++) {
                if(i>0) {
                    newadd[i]=fullAdd(ai[i],bi[i],fullAdd(ai[i-1],bi[i-1],0).charAt(1)).charAt(0);;
                }
                else {
                    newadd[i]=fullAdd(ai[i],bi[i],0).charAt(0);
                }
            }
            return newadd;
        }

        function fullAdd(ai, bi, ci) {
            var ao = ((ai^bi)^ci);
            var co = (((ai^bi)&ci)|(ai&bi));
            return ao+""+co;
        }

        var a = [1,0,1,1];
        var b = [0,1,0,1];
        document.write("a + b = " + add(a,b));

    </script> 
</body>
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, I don't know whether you should use 
for(i=0;i < ai.length; i++) or for(i=ai.length-1; i>=0; i--)

Assume the original one, then maybe you should use:

if (i>0) {
newadd[i]=fullAdd(ai[i],bi[i],**newadd[i]**.charAt(0));
newadd[i+1]=fullAdd(ai[i],bi[i], **newadd[i]**.charAt(1));
}

Comment: yes i just solved it, using a variation of what you used. (ai.length+1 in the for statement)

Answer (score 0):

probably you want

```
document.write("a + b = " + add(a,b));
```

instead of

```
document.write("a + b = " + newadd(a,b);
```

Comment: That would help, but is still not the main problem =(

Comment: for some reason it is adding them as if they were strings, even though that slot is suppose to be overwritten, sorry if im being vague.

Comment: @{Devan Buggay} i still don't know what your code should do.. but obviously you are treating numbers like strings here: `ao+""+co`

Comment: .. maybe you want `(ao+co)+""` ? still not your desired result

Comment: the purpose of this is to take two binary arrays (a and b) and add them together using a string of full adders.
Im just not sure how to do this recursively

Comment: you are initializing newadd = [3] (array with 1 item 3) - is this what you really want? also note that you can convert integer to binary representation: `x.toString(2)`

Comment: yes that is what i needed, im trying to do this solely with binary values, converting to int, adding, then converting back again would be cheating =) thanks for your help though. Knowing me I probably would not have caught that first error.

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance, maybe you have written wrong, maybe it should be :
document.write("a + b = " + add(a,b));

The original lacks ")" at last and use "newadd"

Also, I don't know whether you should use for(i=0;i=0;i--)

Assume the original one, then maybe you should use 
if (i>0) {
    newadd[i]=fullAdd(ai[i],bi[i],newadd[i].charAt(0));

```
newadd[i+1]=fullAdd(ai[i],bi[i], newadd[i].charAt(1));
```

}

Comment: yes, thank you. those have been fixed the add method still does not work properly.